# Erro na ultilizacao do if

Tags: c#

Minha intenção com esse código é mostrar quantos números são ímpares e quantos são pares. (ex:. Impar: 3 Par: 2).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
{
     int SePar, SeImpar, cont;

     SePar = 0;
     SeImpar = 0;
     cont = 0;                               

     if (atividade[i] % 2 == 0)
     {
         SePar = SePar + 1;
     }

     if (atividade[i] % 2 != 0)
     {
         SeImpar = SeImpar + 1;                  
     }

     cont = cont + 1;

     if (cont == 6)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("par: " + SePar + "Impar: " + SeImpar);
     }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

**Primeiro:**

A declaração das variáveis que fazem a contagem dos números que são pares e ímpares deve ser feita fora do laço `for`, caso contrário, as mesmas serão sempre zeradas a cada laço executado.

**Segundo:**

A sua variável `cont`, pode ser substituida pelo `i` pois é ele quem faz o laço continuar através de `i++`.

**Terceiro:**

Neste caso, o teste para verificar se o seu índice (alterei de `cont` para `i`) é `== 6` nunca será atingido, pois o laço começa em 0 e vai até 6, ou seja, na verdade ele vai até 5.

**Código como deveria ser**:

```
public static void par(int[] atividade)
{
    int SePar, SeImpar;

    SePar = 0;
    SeImpar = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 6;i++)
    {                                                
        if (atividade[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            SePar = SePar + 1;
        }

        if (atividade[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            SeImpar = SeImpar + 1;
        }

        if (i == 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("par: " + SePar + " Impar: " + SeImpar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente o 6 era parte do erro, porem ele não esta contando a quantidade de números.

Comment: Se o seu vetor atividade[] não possuir nenhum valor, ele não vai contar quantidade nenhuma. O que tu pediu na pergunta era uma coisa e agora tu quer outra.

Comment: Os valores são inseridos pelo usuário anteriormente.

Comment: Isso, eu verifiquei nas outras perguntas que fez anteriormente que estava com dúvida em relação a isso. Depois que ler os dados do usuário e preencher o vetor, coloque o código acima informado. Ou seja, primeiro o seu programa vai solicitar que o usuário digite os valores. Feito isso, o código acima vai varrer seu vetor com os números e contar quantos são pares e quantos são ímpares.

Comment: Segue o link de como está agora, veja o que acontece na ultima parte (https://dotnetfiddle.net/tCP7u1).

Comment: Acabei de atualizar seu código. Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Mudou muita coisa? Estou sem computador agora.

Comment: Não, apenas mudei o que informei na minha resposta, tirei a declaração das variáveis de dentro do for e coloquei fora. Atualizei minha resposta com seu método. Copie ele e substitua pelo seu método no fiddle e execute. Irá funcionar.

Comment: Vou verificar assim que possível e retorno.

Comment: Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Funcionou ainda tenho muito o que aprender, grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Sem problemas, feliz em ajudar. Lembre-se de marcar como resposta se eu te ajudei! Valeu.

Answer (score 2):

Tem um erro de lógica ai, o count sempre será 0, pois ele esta sendo inicializado dentro do laço de for

O correto é:

```
int SePar, SeImpar, cont;

SePar = 0;
SeImpar = 0;
cont = 0;  

for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
{



     if (atividade[i] % 2 == 0)
     {
         SePar = SePar + 1;
     }

     if (atividade[i] % 2 != 0)
     {
         SeImpar = SeImpar + 1;                  
     }

     cont = cont + 1;


}
 if (cont == 5)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("par: " + SePar + "Impar: " + SeImpar);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para demonstrar o mesmo código, mas refatorado.

```
var atividade = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
var totalImpar = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < atividade.Length; i++)
{
    totalImpar += atividade[i] % 2 == 0
        ? 0
        : 1;
}
Console.WriteLine($"Pares: {atividade.Length - totalImpar}  Impares: {totalImpar}");
```

[Veja funcionando no NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PUtYY6).

Comment: Preciso que ele verifique os valores digitados pelo usuário.

Comment: Mas isso vc sabe fazer, e já está fazendo, pelo que eu vi na sua pergunta. :)